# Wordpress Plugin update error: The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, server, zip

I have a plugin which users are trying to update, but when updating the plugin one is getting following message:

```
An error occurred while updating WooCommerce Simply Order Export Add-on: The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

1. I have checked the disk space on server and it has enough space.

   ```
   /dev/xvda1       30G  2.6G   26G   9% /
   none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
   tmpfs           100M  4.1M   96M   5% /run
   none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
   none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
   ```
2. I also checked my zip file, it is getting extracted properly on my system.

Can you please let me know what could be the issue?

Comment: so this might not be an nginx issue. two things come to my mind: 1) edit your php.ini and comment out `mbstring.func_overload = 7`. 2) is your wordpress up to date? does your wp-plugin folder have correct permissions?

Comment: 1) I have commented out `mbstring.func_overload = 7`, but it didn't worked.

2) WordPress and all other things are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

For me the tmp folder of my server did not had enough space. By increasing space for it I was able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update plugins manually from WordPress backend.

1. Download the latest version of the plugin as an installable zip file.
2. Now, temporarily **deactivate** and **delete** the currently installed plugin as in the next step, we’re going to reinstall it.

   **Note:**
   This should not remove any settings you have made or pages created as they are stored in the database. Still, we always encourage everyone to take backups frequently, just in case something goes wrong.
3. Upload and install the plugin that you downloaded in Step 1 by Add new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For WooCommerce downloadable products, you need to uncheck the "Downloads require login" settings at WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Downloadable Products